# Dealing cards to a player not there

Tags: soft-question

So we had a player at a private tournament not attending that night although he had chips from earlier on. Thus people thought he should have cards just to fold them. Ultimately, one time he didn’t get cards, we took back the cards and shuffled again just so the player not being there could fold some cards.

I don’t get why this is a thing. It’s not like he is away from the table and can come back.

Is this neccessary at all to give cards to people not there?

Comment: I am not clear is the player at the table or not? If he is what is he doing were he is "not attending"?

Comment: is this a tournament or cash game?

Comment: It was a private tournament

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a home game, it does not matter if you deal him cards or not if he is not at the table and will not be back before action gets to him. Casino dealers do this in tournaments because there is a rule that if the player that was absent gets back to the table before it is his/her action then they can play the hand.